# How do I hide the page extension in an angularjs $http request

Tags: php, angularjs

I have something like this:

`$http.post("action/delete.php", gid).success(function(response){
  console.log(response.data);
});`

and I want to hide the .php page extension. Can anyone help!!

Comment: Can you post to "action/delete" (no extension) without Angular? i.e., using a REST client or  curl?

Comment: I'ven't posted with REST or curl before. No idea.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be an issue for angular. You can use `$http` to post to `action/delete` without a problem, **provided that route exists on your server**. What you need to do is look into configuring your back end server to understand that `action/delete` should point to `action/delete.php`. This shouldn't really be a tough thing to do, you'll just need to do some research on your web server settings.

I would suggest learning how to use a REST client (like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US)), as well, so that you can test your routes independently of your front end and make sure they work.